# MySQL Query slow on server but fast on VM

Tags: mysql

I'm having an issue where a query takes less than a second on a VirtualBox machine with 4GB allocated, but more than 20 seconds on an actual server with 16GB.

First here's the relevant part of the schema:

```
accounts (about 13k records)
(
    act_id
)

contacts (about 13k records)
(
    cnt_id,
    cnt_description,
    cnt_hascontact_id,
    cnt_hascontact_type
)

addresses (about 13k records)
(
    add_id,
    add_description,
    add_hasaddress_id,
    add_hasaddress_type
)
```

And here's the query I'm running:

```
SELECT 
    act_id, 
    act_name, 
    act_short, 
    act_ptnumber, 
    cnt_firstname, 
    cnt_lastname, 
    cnt_phone, 
    cnt_email, 
    add_street1, 
    add_city, 
    add_state, 
    add_zip 
FROM accounts  
INNER JOIN addresses ON act_id = add_hasaddress_id  
INNER JOIN contacts ON act_id = cnt_hascontact_id
WHERE act_name LIKE '%<some string>%'
AND cnt_description = 1
AND add_description = 3
GROUP BY act_id
LIMIT 100;
```

Now. The contacts and addresses tables are polymorphic, so there are no indexes here except the accounts.act_id. I thought this mattered, but again, my VM takes less than a second to run the query.

I turned on the profiling on each machine and found that what was taking so long on the real server was 'Copying to tmp table'. This can take 20 seconds by itself. What I find strange is that the VM server doesn't even perform this step. So, I can see why it's so much faster.

Granted the real server is in use, so the database is getting hit by around 100 or so users at a time, as opposed to my VM where only my queries are running. I tried increasing the values for 'tmp_table_size' and 'max_heap_table_size' to 1024M, but that didn't do anything.

Does anyone have any ideas what is going on or how I can fix this? Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:

All tables are InnoDB

Some conf:

VM:

```
tmpdir                               = /var/lib/mysqltmp
table-definition-cache               = 4096
table-open-cache                     = 4096
max-connections                      = 400
max-connect-errors                   = 1000000
max-allowed-packet                   = 16M
skip-name-resolve
wait-timeout                         = 600
key-buffer-size                      = 32M
myisam-sort-buffer-size              = 128M
innodb-file-format                   = Barracuda
```

Server:

```
tmpdir                          = /var/lib/mysqltmp
skip-name-resolve
sql-mode                        = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
table-open-cache                = 4096
table-definition-cache          = 4048
tmp-table-size                  = 2048M
max-heap-table-size             = 2048M
back-log                        = 100
max-connect-errors              = 10000
max-allowed-packet              = 64M
interactive-timeout             = 3600
wait-timeout                    = 600
default-storage-engine          = InnoDB
innodb                          = FORCE
key-buffer-size                 = 64M
myisam-sort-buffer-size         = 128M
```

If a config isn't there then it's default.

EDIT 2:

Here's the *EXPLAIN SELECT* for the queries on each server:

VM:

```
1   SIMPLE  contacts    ref contacts_cnt_description_foreign    contacts_cnt_description_foreign    4   const   5724    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  accounts    eq_ref  PRIMARY,accounts_act_name_unique,accounts_act_type_foreign,accounts_act_businesstype_foreign,accounts_act_parent_foreign    PRIMARY 4   supportnet.contacts.cnt_hascontact_id   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  addresses   ALL addresses_add_description_foreign               12548   Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

Server:

```
1   SIMPLE  contacts    ref contacts_cnt_description_foreign    contacts_cnt_description_foreign    4   const   6155    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  addresses   ALL addresses_add_description_foreign               12903   Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE  accounts    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   supportnet.contacts.cnt_hascontact_id   1   Using where
```

Comment: Have you considered running the tmp tables in MySQL from a RAM disk? Here's a nice article: http://2bits.com/articles/reduce-your-servers-resource-usage-moving-mysql-temporary-directory-ram-disk.html Another thing would be to enable and use query caching?

Comment: When testing stuff for speed, use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE  ...` to make sure your query isn't satisfied from the query cache.

Comment: Storage engine, storage engine configuration? No mention of those?

Comment: What data are you looking for exactly? The databases are using InnoDB. I added in some relevant config info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution ended up being upgrading mysql. Once I moved from 5.5 to 5.6, this issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB -- Good.  But I don't see a setting for innodb_buffer_pool_size.  This is important, and should be about 70% of *available* RAM.  Since the RAM differs, and possibly you are using different versions (which have different defaults), look at `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%';`  There are other important settings that could be defaulted differently.

If other queries are running on the production machine, they could be clobbering the cache (buffer_pool).  This could lead to what you see.  If there are other "big" queries, let's focus on them.

Is the dataset the same size and contents?

Do not use a RAM disk -- the spare space is more useful in the buffer_pool.  And, if you were to have too-big a query, it would crash.

> 'tmp_table_size' and 'max_heap_table_size' to 1024M

That's dangerous!  It could lead to running out of RAM, which would lead to "swapping" which is *much* worse for performance than setting them lower.

Edit (based on EXPLAINs)

Add `INDEX(add_hasaddress_id)` -- Notice how it says `ALL` when reaching into `addresses`?  That implies that no index is useful.  Please provide us with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in case there are other issues.

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size was set to 128M, but I removed it to match my VM (default) to try and make them match. Should that be higher? The VM uses 5.6.22 while the server uses 5.5.36. There possibly may be a discrepancy there. The data is roughly the same. The VM just acts as a test environment where I've cloned the database over. I've removed the tmp table config stuff. I just thought I'd try it, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: 1500M for the 4GB machine; 11G for the 16GB machine.  The version difference is not a big issue.  Do `EXPLAIN SELECT...` on each machine; let's see the ouptut.  (There may be a subtle difference.)  How busy is the actual server when it runs that query too slow?  Is something INSERTing/UPDATEing the tables at the same time?

Comment: I added the pool size back and set it to 8GB. That made no difference. I added the explain selects to the OP. There are some differences, but I don't really know how to interpret them.

Answer (score 0):

With so few records in each table, there is no way it should take 20 seconds, maybe if you forgot indexes. You should check stuff such as locks, firewall blockage or network problems